# Is it bad to represent a one to many relationship without using a foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I apologize if this is a silly question - I am worried that I am having trouble finding answers because my terminology is incorrect. I believe my question is application design-based in nature, but I have not found a similar question because I may be asking incorrectly entirely.

I have two different tables. A a product offer entity table, and a chat entity table. Each of those tables contain the follwing.:

1. A primary key
2. Columns relating to the entity object
3. A chat "reference ID".

The product offer table has a one to many relationship between a product offer and the many chats it could have. However, rather than having a foreign key constraint where each new chat message refers to the ID of the corresponding entity in the product offer table, I have a separate column called "Chat Reference ID". For a single product offer entity, I duplicate its "Chat Reference ID" across all chat messages (or chat entities) that belong to that specific offer.

Here's a visual example of the tables -

Offers:
[image: Offers table representation]

Chats:

[image: Chats table representation]

The chat reference ID is a GUID without hyphens, so it is "guaranteed" to be unique. Each time I do a lookup or an insertion of new chat messages using a LINQ query, I refer to this chat reference ID that belongs to a exactly one meet.

For example:

```
var chats = await _context.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatReference == id).Select( item => new ChatDto
        {
            Sender = item.Sender,
            ChatReference = item.ChatReference,
            Title = item.Title,
            MessageBody = item.MessageBody,
            DateTime = item.DateTime.ToString(),
        }
            ).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Will this give me significant problems later?

More specifically:

1. Will the current design cause significant performance problems?
   And if so,
2. Should I redesign the logic across my application to use a navigation property between the product offer table and chat table - thereby dropping the ChatReference column entirely?

My intuition tells me that this is acceptable, but EF will not enforce the foreign key constraints that would make my development "safer" - I don't know if what I'm saying makes sense, but it's the best way I can express it.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `offers.id`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's what I *ought* to be using, but I have already built the application and it's in use. I'm trying to determine the cost / difficulty in changing its behavior from what it is now to what you've described.

Comment: . . No really big difference if you define the GUID as `unique`.  You incur a bit more overhead because it is bigger than an integer, but that is minimal.